# PySpark throws UnicodeEncodeError when running show

Tags: pyspark, snowflake-cloud-data-platform

I'm trying to read some parquet data and show top 20 rows which throws the following exception:

```
UnicodeEncodeError: 'latin-1' codec can't encode character u'\u2019' in position 2978: ordinal not in range(256)
```

I read that data from Snowflake using python connector and stored it on HDFS in parquet format:

```
sf_cursor.execute(query)
results = sf_cursor.fetchall()
df = self.spark_sql_context.createDataFrame(results, DF_SCHEMA)
```

And here is the read/show code:

```
input_df = spark_sql_context.read.parquet(input_path)
input_df.show(20)
```

Couldn't find anything on setting unicode `utf-8` when reading data from Snowflake so was wondering if there is a way to encode some of the columns to overcome this issue. Any suggestion is much appreciated.

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

Based on niko's answer, this seems to be a known issue and I had to do the following to resolve for now:

```
decode_udf= udf(lambda val: val.encode('utf-8'), StringType())
input_df = input_df.withColumn('COLUMN_NAME', decode_udf('COLUMN_NAME'))
```

Answer (score 0):

We found a similar issue while reading data from Snowflake to Pandas, which might be relevant to your issue.

The problems were:

1. The original data from the source, transformed and dumped into Snowflake had `Latin-1` encoding but while dumping it was forced into `utf-8`. The same error showed up as yours.
2. Some special characters which might need preprocessing.

Find the source data encoding before the snowflake dump.

Snowflake contributors discussed this here, may help you out:
https://github.com/snowflakedb/snowflake-connector-python/issues/574

Comment: Thanks for pointing that out, I ended up using a udf function to fix this for now, till they come up with an actual patch for this issue.